# How store container logs from test-containers?

Tags: java, maven, docker, junit, testcontainers

[Test-containers](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/docker_compose/) project alllows start docker contaniders from compose file. They have [integration with JUnit](https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/junit_4/). But when test phase is finished, all I have is maven log - all started containers were removed by that time. It would be nice if6 for example I run `Application` and `Database` containers 4 times for 4 tests. So maven target folder should contains the following: `target/test-containers/<start-id>/Application.log` and
`target/test-containers/<start-id>/Database.log`.

Is there a way to configure test-containers or JUnit or both to redirect log from started containers into some folder?

Comment: Did you try this? - https://www.testcontainers.org/features/container_logs/